# The domain of convergence

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Help me to find the domain of the function sequence where it convergence uniformly.
$$
x_{n}(t) =  \frac{1}{t^2-nt+1}
$$
For $n > 2$ the function would have points where it is undefined and this confuses me

Comment: @TitoEliatron If $n=4$, then $t^2-nt+1<0$ when $t\in\left(2-\sqrt3,2+\sqrt3\right)$.

Comment: My fault. I meant the discriminant is always positive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $n \gt 2$ $x_n$ is defined on $D_n= (-\infty, \frac{n -\sqrt{n^2 - 4}}{2}) \cup (\frac{n +\sqrt{n^2 - 4}}{2}, \infty)$.

Analyzing $D_n$, you will see that $\bigcap\limits_{n \in \mathbb N} D_n = D=(-\infty , 0]$. Therefore, studying the convergence of the sequence of functions $\{x_n\}$ only makes sense on $D$.

As $x_n(0)=1$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$, $x_n(0)$ converges to $1$. And for $t \lt 0$, $x_n(t)$ converges to $0$. Therefore $\{x_n\}$ converges pointwise on $D$ to the always vanishing map $x(t)$ except at zero where $x(0)=1$.

As $x$ is discontinuous, $\{x_n\}$ which is a sequence of continuous maps doesn't converge uniformly to $x$ on $D$.